Is the area enclosed by p(x,y) always irrational?
Take a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$. Now draw the graph of $p(x,y)=0$. If, like $X^2-Y^2-1$, this turns out to enclose a finite area, is the area enclosed always irrational?
There are some answers that I regard as 'cheating', like combining $4$ lines to make an enclosed square, as this doesn't feel similar to what we are doing with $X^2+Y^2-1$:
$$p=(X-1)(X+1)(Y-1)(Y+1)$$
I think cases like this can be eliminated by requiring that $p$ is irreducible, so more precisely my question is:
Is there an irreducible $p \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ such that a finite nonzero area enclosed by the graph $p(x,y)=0$ is rational?
I've found it quite difficult to even find a polynomial that encloses an area that isn't of the form $a(x)+b(y)-c$, and all of those intuitively feel like they should be irrational, though proving any individual case is presumably extremely difficult, based on how much work it takes to prove $\pi$ is irrational.
I would also be interested in an answer for polynomials in $n>2$ variables. I don't know the answer for $n=1$ either, as things like $X^2-1$ are reducible, though I suspect the answer here might be obvious if I knew a bit of Galois Theory.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli#Further_properties

This question seems to give an example as well.

@user51547 and Greg Martin these are both really nice examples, thank you! When I posed this questions what I had in mind were things like $X^4+Y^4-1$ where it's just a loop disconnected from anything else, so I still wonder if it's possible to find something like that with a rational nonzero area. Though the lemniscate looks tantalisingly close to such a curve.

Somewhat related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_theorem_about_ovals
